# images courrupted

Tags: java, httpresponse, httpserver

I am creating httpServer and I have done writing file server part.
But I am having problems when I download images.

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file_path);

        output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int n = 0;
        while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buffer))) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
        data = output.toByteArray();
         body = new String(data);

 return body
```

I return the body of response to my original method.

```
    // body is return value from above code, header is also  another String return value from 
    // makeHeader method
    String response = header + body;   
     byte[] Response = null;
   try{
      Response = response.getBytes("US-ASCII");
     }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}

      return Response
```

My server is working when it comes to text files, .html, .css but not with images.
Can you please point me out what did I do wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you mix text and binary you are sure to corrupt the data. For example US-ASCII is only 7 bit and any byte with the top bit set will be corrupted.

You should attempt to send the image without using String or text to avoid corruption.

Comment: **any byte witht het op** .. wat is it ??
@Peter Lawrey